# ADF delete doesn't work

Tags: view, oracle-adf, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row from a database table using action "Delete" in taskflow which is called after a button click. This action has a fixed outcome pointing on "Commit" action. Horrible part is that on one table (in separate task flow) this schema works and on the other table (in separate task flow) - doesn't. 
That's not all: I've tried to delete a row from the second table using different approaches (and with Java also), and every time I get the row deleted on the view, but not in the database. 
That's not all TOO: I've implemented "Delete" of the second table row in another application, that uses the same database, and it worked fine!

Does anybody have an idea what the problem is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen if your View Object is n't based on an Entity Object.

Make sure that your VO is an EO based, else while you do the delete operation in the page it will show that the row has been deleted but in database it will be there. If you run the page again(i.e new session) you will be able to see that the row isn't deleted.